# Showing $g(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a function $g:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous sending  with $g(-1)=0=g(1)$. Then for any $g(a)=g(c)=0$ for some $a,c$ again within minus one to one, then there exists a $b$ within $a,c$ such that $g(b)=0$, how can I show that $g(x)=0$?

I thought since the function is continuous on the interval and $g(x)>0$ for some $x$ inside the interval, then there is a neighbourhood of x in which $g(x)>0$

So then with $g(x)>0$, then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $g(x)\geq\epsilon$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

Then I am not sure whether to use Bolzano-Weierstras or the EVT?

Could anyone give me a hint? Or am I wrong so far?

Comment: Does the problem state that $g(x)>0$? for some $x\in[-1,1]$?

Comment: It does not unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $g(x_0)\ne0$ for some $x_0\in(-1,1)$. Define
$$c=\inf_{x\in[x_0,1]}\{x|g(x)=0\}$$
$$a = \sup_{x\in[-1,x_0]}\{x|g(x)=0\}$$
Then there is no $b$ between these $a$ and $c$ such that $g(b)=0$. This leads to a contradiction (note that $a<x_0$ and $c>x_0$ by continuity of $g$).

Comment: Thank you! And yes will change my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that you haven't define the function $f$? I just consider $f$ is the same function as $g$. I think you should explain why $f(x) \ge \epsilon$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.

My idea: $O=\{x: g(x)\neq 0\}$ is an open set. Take a max open interval $(a,b)$ of $O$ such that $g(a)=g(b)=0$, then there is no $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $g(c)=0$. This contradictory shows that $O=\phi$. In this way we also build up a proof.